# WordPress multisite search error "Call to undefined function wpzoom_wpmu()"

Tags: wordpress, wpmu

[image]
<sub>(source: [dancedric.com](http://dancedric.com/files/error.png))</sub>

what's wrong here? When I search something, this is what comes up. I don't even know how to interpret this error.

In search.php, it refers to wpzoom_wpmu(). where is wpmu declared? where is it saved? am I looking at the right one?I don't know why it's trying to refer to c:/. This is a dev site online

Answer (score 1):

As the error message says: `wpzoom_wpmu()` isn't defined anywhere, which is the problem. `C:\wamp\www\wp-content\themes\deadline-zenko\search.php` is attempting to call the function, but because the function hasn't been loaded anywhere in the code, PHP can't run it. Have a look on line 29 of that search.php file and you'll see where it's being called.

I'm presuming that the function you want to include is this:

```
function wpzoom_wpmu ($img) {
        global $blog_id;
  $imageParts = explode('/files/', $img);
        if (isset($imageParts[1])) {
                $img = '/blogs.dir/' . $blog_id . '/files/' . $imageParts[1];
        }
        return($img);
}
```

Make sure that you're including - include() or include_once() or require() or require_once() -  the library that contains this function.

And the references to C:\ are references to the server's C drive, not yours.